# JavascriptExecutor executeScript not returning

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how can I execute and get value of `res`  in webDriver

```
for (WebElement elems:links){

   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

  String script = 
  "function  tryRecursiveSearch (node) { "+
   "  var child "+
   " for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) { "+
  " var len =  node.children.length;"+
    "  child = node.children[i];"+

  "  if (child.tagName === 'A'){ "+
     "  return child "+
      "       } "+
  "  else {  "+ 
   "      return tryRecursiveSearch (child); "+
     "     } "+
  "  } "+

"} " ;

WebElement res = (WebElement)js.executeScript("tryRecursiveSearch(argument[0])",elems); // it exits here , gives no error
System.out.println(res); //doesnt print anything

  }
```

when I run the JavaScript code in browser console and pass element, it returns correctly  `a` element

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print the value of your webelement, just use getText().

```
System.out.println(res.getText());
```

Or if you want to know the value of the attribute then use getAttribute() method like so..

```
System.out.println(res.getAttribute("href"));
```

The above code will print the attribute of href. Likewise, customize it according to your need.